# I'm looking for a software I can use to screen share a window with audio

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, screen, sharing

I'm looking for some software I can use to share my screen with people remotely.  Initially, I had intended to use discord screen share, but it won't share my computer audio.  I tried using google hangouts as well and faced the same issue.  Is there a software out there that I can use to share my screen with it's audio?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS The people I want to share with are using Windows 10 and macOS

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact use case: [OBS](https://obsproject.com) and [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/) could be a good candidate.

OBS is a screen recording software, while Teamviewer is remote access and support application that supports audio throughput for the remote viewer.

Comment: Thanks, we were looking for something that could be used to play games/watch movies remotely with.  I did attempt  to stream to Twitch using OBS, but the delay between me and my friends was annoyingly large.  I did test teamviewer and I wasn't able to hear any of my computer's audio through it.  Additionally, full remote access isn't necessary, I just want them to be able to see/hear my computer.  

Other things to note:
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
The people I want to share with are using Windows 10 and macOS

Comment: For watching movies remotely: https://www.plex.tv/
(they recently announced a "watch together" feature: https://www.plex.tv/blog/coming-in-hot-watch-together-chill/)